# Performance Issue - Page slow when kendo grid is loaded fully

Tags: angular, performance, angular-material, kendo-grid, slowdown

In page, I'm using 2 components.
1st component consist of many angular material **mat-select** dropdown.
2nd component consist of kendo grid without virtual scroll and without pagination.

When the kendo grid is empty, page is fast and when I click the dropdown of 1st component it opening fastly.

when the kendo grid is loaded with 500 rows of data (2nd component), the whole page become slow, when I clicked mat-select dropdown which is located in 1st component, it also working slowly

I'm using angular 15 and latest kendo version, in angular 14 also same issue occurring.

I'm now allowed to change the kendo grid with virtual scroll or pagination in that page.

I don't know why all components in that page is getting slow.

Comment: Putting 500 mat-select components on a page can certainly cause issues. I would see if pagination or virtual scroll improves your performance.